# Can a command typeset its argument without letting latex take it into account for bounding box?

Tags: line-spacing, bounding-box

Quite often, especially when preparing slides, vertical space is precious. However, there is no automatic equivalent of "vertical kerning of lines", by which you would reduce or even have a negative line spacing when the highest elements of the lower line are on the right hand side while the upper line occupies only the left hand side.

A small example:

```
\begin{minipage}{7cm}
Equation:
$$a+b+c+d=\overbrace{x+y+z}^{\text{unknown}}$$
\end{minipage}
```

[image: output of code]

With commands such as `\hphantom`, you can have Latex *not* typeset the argument and reserve the space in bounding box. Can one do the reverse, display the overbrace above without updating the bounding box of the equation?

Comment: you can use `\vspace{-1in}` before the display, or `\text{\smash{unknown}`  to hide the height of `unknown` or `\smash{$\displaystyle a+....` to hide the height of the whole display or ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\smash`, maybe in connection with some `\vphantom`, which is not necessary in this case as the line already contains some non-smashed material. Of course you become responsible for avoiding clashes, but all presentations require some amount of visual formatting anyway.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{7cm}
Equation:
\[
a+b+c+d=\smash{\overbrace{x+y+z}^{\text{unknown}}}
\]
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Avoid `$$` even in minipages.

[image]